# Xcode autolayout - dynamic constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout

In the picture below you can see "prototype" of menu I need to create.

[image]

I managed to do it with only single item in the middle, but how can I achieve exactly the same result as you can see in the picture ?

Each circle should be a separate element.

Comment: Check out this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26373646/952608 - this details how you make a subview percentage based compared to the superview. In your example, you'll need to set each subview with a 0.33 multiplier (33% width)

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your problem, then following is the solution.

Add following constraints as shown in screenshot, I have also included result achieved in simulator with these constraints in screenshot.

And for setting borderWidth and corner radius I have used run time attributes which is also shown in screenshot.

Edit- Added new ScreenShot.

[image]