# How to center and reduce the width of buttons inside a UIStackView

Tags: xcode, swift, uistackview

In a vertical `UIStackView` I have stacked four UIButtons. The `UIStackView` is centered (vertically and horizontally), the left side corresponds to the left edge of the device and the right side to the right. Inside the stackview, the buttons take all the horizontal space the stackview takes, so the stackview and its content share their width.

Now, I want to reduce the width of my buttons, so that they are 80% the width of the container (on any device except for iPad) and I want to center them too.

How can I do? I need a solution either in code (Swift) and using any possible property I can't find in XCode

Comment: r u using storyboard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of pinning the stack view to both sides of its superview, give it a width constraint that causes it to be 80% of the width of its superview.

Comment: Hi matt, thanks, this is the solution I had in mind but I thought it was possible something different. I love your books.   :-)

Comment: Thanks! :) See also this question and answer on how to use the `multiplier` of a constraint to specify a percentage of the total: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373598/how-to-create-percentage-of-total-width-using-autolayout/26373646#26373646

Answer (score 0):

The best working solution is 
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:self.stackview.frame-30).isActive = true

This works perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks (nowadays I'm not even doing any mobile development anymore!)