# UIStackView with proportional width to superview

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit, uistackview, ios-autolayout

I need to increase the size of horizontal UIStackView depending on the width of superview. All buttons in UIStackView are fixed width & height. I tried setting autolayout constraint with stackview.width = superview.width * 0.3 but it messes the superview width. What is the correct way to achieve it?

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373598/how-to-create-percentage-of-total-width-using-autolayout

Answer (score 2):

This

```
1-"buttons in UIStackView are fixed width & height"
```

Contradicts

```
2- "stackview.width = superview.width * 0.3"
```

As you need to make something of them flexible

So either ignore static widths,heights for the buttons and set

```
stackView.distriburion = .fillEqually
```

to make them equally spreaded , Or ignore proportional width of the stackView and set

```
stackView.distriburion = .fill
```

to make it grow according to size

Answer (score 0):

> I need to increase the size of horizontal UIStackView depending on the width of superview. All buttons in UIStackView are fixed width & height. I tried setting autolayout constraint with stackview.width = superview.width * 0.3 but it messes the superview width

I don't know what you mean by "it messes the superview width". This is what the constraint *multiplier* is for. If you are using the multiplier correctly, you will get the desired result.

Comment: It makes superview width smaller. Superview width is reset to 0.3 of original width.

Comment: Then you’re not doing what I said. You are not using the constraint multiplier, or not using it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to play with the horizontal hugging priority and the horizontal compression resistance priority.

By decreasing the compression and hugging priority of you stackView you tell to the autoLayout to size the stackView to fit the superView and not the superView to fit the stackView.

Hope it helps